# Incorrect function on php script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple contact form I'm trying to implement but I'm getting an "incorrect function" error when I try to launch it. My code below is as follows, and when I click submit, it redirects to

> http://mywebsite.com/contactme.php

but with the text "Incorrect function" and that's it. My debug on firefox shows the following error:

```
        POST http://www.mywebsite.com/v/vspfiles/contactform/contactme.php [HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 33ms]
    13:54:52.368 The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. 
The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
```

I am using volusion software if that helps. But I have no idea if the error is in my code or because my webhost won't allow the function. Can someone give me some insight? I have tried the "contactme.php" page with and without the doctype declared. My two files are below. I do not have an "error.htm" page.

contact.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact</title>
</head>
<body >
<div id="contact-area">
            <form method="post" action="/v/vspfiles/contactform/contactme.php">
                <h3>Contact us</h3>

                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />

                <label for="City">City:</label>
                <input type="text" name="City" id="City" />

                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />

                <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
                <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
            </form>         
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>        
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

contactme.php:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "email@gmail.com";
$EmailTo = "email@gmail.com";
$Subject = "contact form";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// informs user they submitted, redirects to homepage 
if ($success){
  alert("Thank you for your interest in our multiple sample processing system. A member of the Claremont Bio team will respond to you shortly.");
  window.location.assign(location.hostname);
}
else{    
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: You are mixing PHP and JS code...

Comment: I don't think you understand the difference between client and server sided code.

Comment: HTTP Error
`405 Method Not Allowed`
The method specified in the Request Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the request. Please ensure that you have the proper MIME type set up for the resource you are requesting.

Comment: not sure you need the html and body tags in contactme.php, I dont see any HTML in there...

Comment: @m0atz, I thought so, but the error led me to believe maybe it needed it, I edited it out of the code

Comment: @Glavic where am I mixing the code? can you point it out please?

Comment: @RUJordan, a little more information might be great, that doesn't exactly help me.

Comment: `if ($success){
  alert("Thank you for your interest in our multiple sample processing system. A member of the Claremont Bio team will respond to you shortly.");
  window.location.assign(location.hostname);
}` right there

Comment: after `if($success)` you mix javascript code with php code. You have either enclose php or echo that commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert("Thank you for your interest in our multiple sample processing system. A member of the Claremont Bio team will respond to you shortly.");
  window.location.assign(location.hostname);
```

This is not valid php code, it is javascript. It definitely should not be in your php script.

As an alternative, in your `if($success)` condition you could redirect to a "success.php" page. For example:

```
if($success){
    header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/success.php");
}
```

Comment: @Jason Fingar I made the change (the alternative one) and I still have that same error. Anything else to check?

Comment: After `header('location: ...');` use `exit;`

Answer (score 0):

An example of a contact.php page I use is as follows, note as per Jorge's comments, I make use of echoing the command...

```
<?php

// configuration
require("../includes/config.php");

// if form was submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // submission is sanitised using the "query" function
    $name = check_input($_POST["name"]);
    $email = check_input($_POST["email"]);
    $phone = check_input($_POST["phone"]);
    $message = check_input($_POST["message"]);
    $category = $_POST["category"];

    switch($category)
    {
        // do some checking here
    }

    // insert user into db

    // Success Message
    $success = "
    <div class=\"row-fluid\">
        <div class=\"span11\">
            <div class=\"alert alert-block alert-success\" id=\"thanks\">
                <h4>Got it!</h4>
                <br/>    
                <p>I'll be in touch within 24 hours. <strong> Promise.</strong></p>
                <br/>
                <p>In the meantime, why not check out my Facebook page...</p>
                <br/>
                <a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/myfacebooksite\" target=\"_blank\">www.facebook.com/myfacebooksite</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    ";

    $subject = 'New Website Message!';
    $mailto  = 'your@email.com';

    // HTML for email to send submission details
    $body = "
    <br>
    <p>The following information was submitted through the contact form on your website:</p>
    <p><b>Name</b>: $name<br>
    <b>Email</b>: $email<br>
    <b>Phone</b>: $phone<br>
    <b>Category</b>: $category<br>
    <b>Message:</b>: $message<br>
    ";

    $headers = "From: $name <$email> \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $mailtext = "<html><body>$body</body></html>";

    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $mailtext, $headers)) {
        echo "$success"; // success
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'Form submission failed. Please try again...'; // failure
    }
}
else
{
    // else render form
    redirect("/index.html");
}
?>
```

edit:

my contact form page has the following js:

```
// do the mailing
  $('#contact_form').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //Prevents default submit
      var form = $(this); 
      var post_url = form.attr('action'); 
      var post_data = form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'contact.php',
          data: post_data,
          success: function(msg) {
              $(form).fadeOut(200, function(){
                  form.html(msg).fadeIn();
              });
          }
      });
  });
```

Hope that helps steer you...

Answer (score 0):

So turns out this isn't my error, this is my webhost. Had to call them up and they told me they don't support PHP currently. so I'm off to rewrite this is javascript. I'll give the answer to Jason as his was the most technically correct and pointed out the error. Thanks guys.